# Google API application restrictions with Cloud Run

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-cloud-run

I have a website that use Nuxt for server render and deployed using Cloud Run.

It pulls the YouTube videos of a channel using the YouTube Data API key and pre-rendered it before send to the browser. This is for SEO purpose.

Currently I using the API key restriction option `HTTP referrers (web sites)` to only allow access from my website.

But on the server when it pre-rendered the API is blocked.

Is there a good solution to add the referrer and allow for Cloud Run to use the API key?

Comment: As far as I know, the option `HTTP referrers (web sites)` -- i.e. the `Website restrictions` section of that page -- allows you to have set multiple websites.

Comment: Can the http referrers be an IP address and not a domain name?

Comment: It is allow to have multiple sites. IP address is another restriction option. The problem is I don't know where the request will be originated from when query from Cloud Run so I cannot enter the correct address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is in my opinion is not the best yet.

I have 2 separate key `Youtube API server` and `Youtube API web`.

- server key has no restriction
- web key is restrict to `HTTP referrers (web sites)`

In my Nuxt app, when query for server side render, I use the `server key`. Then when it passed to client side. It use the `web key`.

This way I protect the "no restriction" key.

I'm not sure any better solution but I imagine in the future, `server key` without restrictions can be use for multiple services other than Youtube API and only server side have access to that key.